# Difficulty understanding why both these slicing methods for matrices are not equivalent in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]])
print(a[0:1,1])
print(a[:,1])
```

Output:

```
[2]
[2 5]
```

I apologize for the relatively basic question, but I've been unable to find the answer on google. Why aren't these two equivalent?

Furthermore, the first code works when I change the range from 0:2, or 0:200, etc. any number which is larger than the rows of the matrix, why is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, I think it is better to think of the integer indexers as numbers in between the "cells".

So, if you slice 0:1, you are getting only the value "a" for the image below or the zero element.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Because slice don’t consider last value and 0:1 is equivalent to 0 raw. If you want to take first two values use 0:2.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]])

temp1 = a[0:1,:]
temp2 = a[0:2,:]
temp3 = a[0:3,:]

print(a[0:1,:])
print(a[0:2,:])
print(a[0:3,:])

print(temp1[:,1])
print(temp2[:,1])
print(temp3[:,1])


print(a[:,1])
```

Following code will output:

```
[[1 2 3]]
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
[2]
[2 5]
[2 5 8]
[2 5 8]
```

I hope this example clarifies your question